# HP 5820 Switch in BGP routing

Tags: routing, bgp

I planning to build an isp network with 2 redundant BGP routers. After a bit of research I found strange that even switches can do BGP, at least that's what it says in their manual.

Considering how cheap they are compared to a modular HP switch or router, I think there is some catch here.

Does anyone have experience with these type of equipment?
HP 5820-14XG-SFP+ Switch with 2 Slots

http://www8.hp.com/emea_africa/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=4177517

Could they do more than 2 linux servers with 10gbe cards in them running bird?

Thanks

Comment: This may be best for the http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: The BGP routing table on these switches appears to have a limit of 16k entries. [HP 5820 Switch Series - BGP Routing Table is Full](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Dmmr_kc-0112286-4%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1412779491459.876444892.492883150)

Comment: The HP 5820 is a routers not a switch, as it clearly works at the IP level!

Answer (score 3):

The intended use for BGP on HP's  5000 series (comware) switches is for smaller internal BGP routing schemes with a few hundred subnets to route. If you intend to peer them with Internet routers I would recommend something more purpose built.

Comment: This. To elaborate, most switches do not have the memory required to hold a full route table, let alone from multiple providers. When they have a BGP implementation it is with the expectation of the majority of routes been covered by default.